# Testing function with pointer parameter C

Tags: c, function, pointers, testing, program-entry-point

I started learning C this week and here is the first difficulty I'm encountering with pointers.

I would like to test this function:

```
void    ft_ultimate_div_mod(int *a, int *b)
    {
        int *tmp;

        if (b != 0)
        {
            *tmp = *a % *b;
            *a = *a / *b;
            *b = *tmp;
        } 
}
```

But I can't figure out the main using pointers. My program is not printing anything with:

```
int     main(void)
{
    int *a;
    int *b;

    *a = 5;
    *b = 3;

    ft_ultimate_div_mod(a, b);
    printf("%d", *a);
    printf("%d", *b);

    return (0);
```

}

What can I do? Thx!

Comment: Don't declare pointers in `main` and use the adressof operator `&`

Comment: @UnholySheep I removed the `*'s` and called `ft_ultimate_div_mod(&a, &b)` with no luck

Comment: `int* tmp;` should also be `int tmp;` (and remove the `*` from all uses of `tmp`)

Comment: b is a pointer. did you mean  if (*b != 0)   ?

Comment: @purec You are right. He meant *b != 0.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it does not make sense to declare the variable `tmp` as having the type `int *`. The variable is used to store an object of the type `int` so it has to have the type `int`. Otherwise you are using an uninitialized pointer with an indeterminate value that results in undefined behavior of the program.

Also as the variable is used in the compound statement of the if statement then it should be declared in the blco scope of the if statement.

These declarations in main

```
int *a;
int *b;
```

als do not make sense.

What you mean is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_ultimate_div_mod(int *a, int *b)
{
    if ( *b != 0 )
    {
        int tmp = *a % *b;
        *a = *a / *b;
        *b = tmp;
    } 
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 3;

    ft_ultimate_div_mod( &a, &b );

    printf( "%d %d\n", a, b );

    return 0;
}
```

The function  `ft_ultimate_div_mod` excepts its arguments by reference because it tries to change their original values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations about the reference, this is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You declare int `*tmp` in your function. That is a pointer to an int sized bit of memory that can store an int. You never point it anywhere however so `*tmp = *a % *b;` will do a mod of a an b and then crash when it stores it using an uninitialized pointer.

Change the `*tmp` to just tmp so then your code becomes:

```
void ft_ultimate_div_mod(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp;

    if (a && b)
    {
        tmp = *a % *b;
        *a = *a / *b;
        *b = tmp;
    } 
}
```